# Determining exactly which IAM permission is missing when a CF stack update fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudfront

When a CloudFormation stacks fails to deploy due to missing permissions, you'll get more or less useful error messages.

In my case, my CI pipeline deploys a CloudFormation template for a web application, including a S3 bucket, a CloudFront distribution and some other resources.
The CI uses a IAM user.

Most times this works fine, however, sometimes my CI user gets an error like this:

```
The following resource(s) failed to update: [CloudFrontDistribution].
Resource handler returned message: "Access denied for operation 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'." 
(RequestToken: 1014641b-7590-f7b3-2ea2-1ddcd32e92a3, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)
```

In order to give my CI IAM user as narrow permission set as possible, I wanted to know exactly what's required. However, the error message above doesn't specify any IAM action; in fact the message is quite cryptic saying that the failed *operation* is `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` (which is a resource type, not an operation or IAM action).
I went to CloudTrail to see if I could find an event with an AccessDenied error for this user, but with no luck. I could only see a `ExecuteChangeSet` action which from CloudTrail's point of view was successful.

Since I couldn't find any more details in any logs and I didn't want to play trial and error with 50+ actions that may or may not be needed, eventually I gave up and added `CloudFront:*` to my IAM user's permission set. However, this bothers me; I'd like to understand what was required instead of taking the wildcard route, since doing so creates way too broad permissions, which in turn is bad security practice.

Is there a way to find out more details about why a CF template failed to deploy when the reason is insufficient permissions, such as in the case above?

Comment: Try and see. That's the usual way unfortunately.

Comment: As @Marcin said, this is a trial and error process unfortunately, this is how we do it over here as well. You should be able to get the exact rule needed from the CloudFormation Stack in the console, in the events tab!

Comment: @furydrive the reason for asking is that the events tab didn't show anything useful, as it usually, does, but only the cryptic message in the question.

Comment: Usually access denied without extra information ends up being a Network issue so I would check Security Groups and if you use a VPC most probably issue is you have not allowed the cloudfront service to communicate with your vpc, this should be covered by adding 443 as inbound with source your VPCs CIDR

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and could only resolve it the same way you did with: cloudfront:*.  I agree, this is troubling.

Answer (score 0):

I Fix this issue adding the following permission, even for List permissions are wide open at least is better than cloudfront:*

```
"cloudfront:GetDistribution",
"cloudfront:CreateDistribution",
"cloudfront:DeleteDistribution",
"cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
"cloudfront:List*",
```